# How to keep sorting order when using pagination?

Tags: javascript, php, mysqli

I can't figure how to keep sort order when I click on next page. On that page products aren't sorted by selected option, and this is problem. When option Naziv is clicked, only on first page products are sorted by Naziv and when going to next page products aren't sorted by Naziv and they should be.

I've tried with:
`page=$next&order=$order`. But this doesn't work correctly.

Does anyone have some advice how to fix this.

```html
<html>
<body>
<div>
<div id="container">
    <div>         
        <select name="filter" onchange="window.location.href = 'laptop?order=' + this.value">
            <option>Poredaj po: </option>
            <option value="naziv">Naziv</option>
            <option value="cijenaasc">Cijena Manja-Veća</option>
            <option value="cijenadesc">Cijena Veća-Manja</option>
         </select>

        <form id="Forma" method='post' action="usporedi">
             <?php
                 // 5. record shown amount
                 $per_page = 10;
                 // 7. current page
                 if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
                      $page = 1;
                 } else {
                      $page = $_GET['page'];
                 }

                 // 4. mysql start possition
                 if ($page <= 1) {
                     $start = 0;
                 } else {
                     $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
                 }

                 // 2. main sql query
                 $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='laptop'";
                 $order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : '';
                 if ($order) {
                     switch ($order) {
                         case 'cijenaasc':
                             $order = 'cijena';
                             $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='laptop' ORDER BY CAST(cijena AS DECIMAL(8,2)) ASC ";
                             break;

                         case 'naziv':
                             $order = 'naziv';
                             $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='laptop' ORDER BY naziv ASC ";
                             break;

                         case 'cijenadesc':
                             $order = 'cijena';
                             $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='laptop' ORDER BY CAST(cijena AS DECIMAL(8,2)) DESC ";
                             break;
                         }
                    }

                    // 7. How much records are in database
                    $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $query));

                    // 7. How much pages are at all
                    $num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $per_page);

                    // 6. Appends limit for shown records
                    $query .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";

                    // 3. Show all records
                    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $id = $row ['id'];

                        print
                                "<div id='proizvod'></br><a style='text-decoration:none; color:black;' class='two' href='proizvod.php?id=$id' >" . $row["naziv"] . "" .
                                "<p><img src=" . $row["slika"] . " width='200px' height='200px' style='border-radius: 15px;'></p>" .
                                "<p style='font-size:20px'><b> Cijena za gotovinu: " . $row["cijena"] . " KN </b></p>" .
                                "<pre id='pre1'>" . $row["opis"] . "</pre>" .
                                "</a></div>";
                    }
                    ?>
        </form>
    </div>     
    <br/>
    <div id="pagination">
        <?php
            // 8. Prev numbers, next links
            $prev = $page - 1;
            $next = $page + 1;

            // prev
            if ($prev > 0) {
                echo "<a style='text-decoration:none; color: blue;' href='?page=$prev&order=$order'><b><</b></a> ";
            }
            //numbers
            $number = 1;
            for ($number; $number <= $num_pages; $number +=1) {
                if ($page == $number) {
                    echo " <b> $number </b> ";
                } else {
                    echo " <a style='text-decoration:none; color: blue;' href='?page=$number&order=$order'>$number</a> ";
                }
            }

            // next
            if ($page < ceil($num_rows / $per_page)) {
                echo " <a  style='text-decoration:none; color: blue;'  href='?page=$next&order=$order'><b>></b></a> ";
            }
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To keep sort order when paging trough pages variable

$order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : '';

must be in "div id='pagination'".

```
 <html>
        <body>

            <div id="container">

                <?php

                $per_page = 10;

                if (!isset($_GET['page'])) {
                    $page = 1;
                } else {
                    $page = $_GET['page'];
                }


                if ($page <= 1) {
                    $start = 0;
                } else {
                    $start = $page * $per_page - $per_page;
                }

                $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='smartphone' ORDER BY id ASC ";
                // 7. How much records are in database
                $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($con, $query));

                // 7. How much pages are at all
                $num_pages = ceil($num_rows / $per_page);
                ?>

                <div id="gumb"> 
                    <div id="usporedivanje">
                        <input type='submit' form='Forma' name='usporedi' disabled='disabled' id='usporedi' value='Usporedi' onmouseover="" style="cursor: pointer;" />

                    <div id='sortiranje'>
                        <select id='filter' style="font-size:20px; height:50px; border: 5px solid #099CDB; border-radius: 10px; border-color: #099bcd;" name="filter" onchange="window.location.href = 'smartphone?order=' + this.value">
                            <option>Poredaj po: </option>
                            <option value="naziv">Naziv</option>
                            <option value="cijenaasc">Cijena Manja-Veća</option>
                            <option value="cijenadesc">Cijena Veća-Manja</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>

                    <br/>

                    <form id="Forma" method='post'>
                        <?php

                        $order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : '';
                        if ($order) {
                            switch ($order) {
                                case 'cijenaasc':
                                    $order = 'cijena';
                                    $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='smartphone' ORDER BY CAST(cijena AS DECIMAL(8,2)) ASC ";
                                    break;

                                case 'naziv':
                                    $order = 'naziv';
                                    $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='smartphone' ORDER BY naziv ASC ";
                                    break;

                                case 'cijenadesc':
                                    $order = 'cijena';
                                    $query = "SELECT *, FORMAT(cijena,2,'de_DE') as cijena FROM artikli WHERE kategorija='smartphone' ORDER BY CAST(cijena AS DECIMAL(8,2)) DESC ";
                                    break;
                            }
                        }

                        $query .= " LIMIT $start, $per_page";

                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                            $id = $row ['id'];

                            print
                                    "<div id='proizvod'></br><a style='text-decoration:none; color:black; font-size:20px;' class='two' href='proizvod.php?id=$id' ><b>" . $row["naziv"] . "</b>" .
                                    "<p><img src=" . $row["slika"] . " width='200px' height='200px' style='border-radius: 15px;'></p>" .
                                    "<p style='font-size:20px'><b> Cijena za gotovinu: " . $row["cijena"] . " KN </b></p>" .
                                    "<pre id='pre1'>" . $row["opis"] . "</pre>" .
                                    "</a></div>";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </form>

                <div id="pagination">
                    <?php

                    $prev = $page - 1;
                    $next = $page + 1;

                    $order = isset($_GET['order']) ? $_GET['order'] : '';


                    if ($prev > 0) {
                        echo "<a style='text-decoration:none; font-size:30px; color: #099BCD;' href='?page=$prev&order='$order'><b><</b></a> ";

                    }

                    $number = 1;
                    for ($number; $number <= $num_pages; $number +=1) {
                        if ($page == $number) {
                            echo " <b style='font-size:30px; color: #099BCD;'> $number </b> ";
                        } else {
                            echo " <a style='text-decoration:none; font-size:30px; color: #099BCD;' href='?page=$number&order=$order'>$number</a> ";
                        }
                    }

                    if ($page < ceil($num_rows / $per_page)) {
                        echo " <a  style='text-decoration:none; font-size:30px; color: #099BCD;'  href='?page=$next&order=$order'><b>></b></a> ";
                    }
                    ?>

                </div>

            </div>

    <?php include "footer.php"; ?>
        </body>
    </html>
```